# Displaying selected items of listbox into a message box

Tags: c#, .net, listbox, messagebox

I am able to display multiple selected items from a listbox into a text box on a button click but how can I display the same on a message box? I mean displaying first item on a messagebox is not an issue but multiple items at once is. Suggestions please...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace cities
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Clear();
            foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
            {
               textBox1.AppendText(selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }


        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create temporary variable to save text in it and then create a messagebox.

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    message.AppendLine(selectedItem.ToString());
}
MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single string based on all the `SelectedItems` and then display that in the MessageBox. Like

```
string str = string.Join(",",
                        listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().Select(r => r.ToString()));
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your button click -

```
        textBox1.Clear();
        string str = string.Empty;
        foreach (object selectedItem in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            str += selectedItem.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        textBox1.Text = str;
        MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Comment: I think if theres too many selected items then the ok button and possibly top bar will go off the screen :)